# Como criar um atalho no desktop do mobile de um Web App?

Tags: javascript, mobile

Eu tenho um web app pronto e publicado.

Existe a possibilidade de criar um ícone do web app no Desktop dos Sistemas iOS e Android automaticamente ou, pelo menos, através de uma pergunta de confirmação?

Espero ter sido claro, pois esta questão nem o Google entendeu...

Somente um adendo:
Criar um app simples somente com uma caixa de texto e um botão, onde eu digitasse uma URL e o botão disparasse um evento para criar o atalho já resolveria o meu problema!

Comment: Você quer detectar se o browser é iOs ou Android e nesse caso exibir um icon? entendo correcto?

Comment: Sergio, independente do sistema operacional (iOS ou Android) e do Browser (Chrome, Opera, etc), eu preciso que, uma vez a URL acessada, crie-se automaticamente um ícone na área de trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar as seguintes tags

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://arpadesign.com.br/img/logo_touch_57x57.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://arpadesign.com.br/img/logo_touch_72x72.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://arpadesign.com.br/img/logo_touch_114x114.png"/>

<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="http://arpadesign.com.br/img/logo_touch_57x57.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://arpadesign.com.br/img/logo_touch_72x72.png"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="http://arpadesign.com.br/img/logo_touch_114x114.png"/>

<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://arpadesign.com.br/img/logo_touch.png">

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1-Create function to call intent of shortcut:

```
private void criarAtalho() {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
        SplashScreen.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "nomeDaApp");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, 
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), 
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

2-write on OnCreat the call of function:

```
if(!getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).
    getBoolean("IS_ICON_CREATED", false)){

    criarAtalho();
    getSharedPreferences("APP_PREFERENCE", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).
        edit().putBoolean("IS_ICON_CREATED", true).commit();
}
```

3-set the permissions on manifest:

```
<uses-permission
android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Comment: Pedro, logo abaixo da sua pergunta existe o link **editar**, utilize-o para alterar sua pergunta e inclua lá o texto que inseriu nestes comentários.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve ter os aplicativos publicados nas lojas App Store e GooglePlay!

Como Já tem o aplicativo pronto na Web, uma opção seria desenvolver os aplicativos para IOS e Android com a única função de carregar a pagina web.

E na sua pagina fazer uma verificação se o usuário esta num dispositivo mobile e sugerir que baixem o app!

Mas precisa verificar se A Google e Apple estão aceitando isso!

Isso porque criar um atalho direto ainda não é possível.

Comment: Pode explicar o por que do -1 na resposta!

Comment: Bom não explicou mas eu fui atras de saber e arrumei um cara para te ajudar! De nada!

Comment: Vinicius, não fui eu que mandei esse -1 (acho que, por ser novo no site, nem posso fazer isso). De qualquer forma, te agradeço... Infelizmente, já descobri que o que queria não pode ser feito de jeito nenhum! Abraços, Alexandre

Comment: Maravilha Alexandre. Mesmo com essas tags, porque eu também não sabia que dava para colocar um atalho no IOS e Android, para uma página web, e com essas tags é possível, mas beleza, pensei que tivesse sido você, e não tinha entendido o motivo, mas como não foi foi mal.